# How to populate a map using uniform initialization with insert method

Tags: c++11

I have something like this

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::string>> p;
```

and i am trying this

```
p.insert({ 0x00 ,{0x03,"Custom"} });
```

no instance of overloaded function ........ takes the parameter list error
Can anyone please tell me the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One pair of braces is missing. The value of `p` is the collection - `unordered_map`, so by inserting at `0x00` as the key you can put the collection for example which consists of 2 items, the syntax is:

```
p.insert({ 0x00 , { {0x03,"Custom"},{0x04,"Custom2"} } });
                  ^ ^brace for item ^brace for item  ^
                  |->begin collections               |-> end collections
```

so when the collection has one items, syntax should be:

```
p.insert({ 0x00 , { {0x03,"Custom"} } });
```